# Categorize dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

so I am making a quiz app. My dictionary looks something like this:

```
struct QData {
    
    let questions = [
        Question(category: "Cat1", currentquestion: "What is 1+1?", answers: ["1", "2", "3", "4"], correctAnswerIndex: 1),
        Question(category: "Cat1", currentquestion: "What is 2+1?", answers: ["1", "6", "3", "5"], correctAnswerIndex: 2),
        Question(category: "Cat2", currentquestion: "What is 0?", answers: ["1", "3", "2", "0"], correctAnswerIndex: 3)
    ]
    
    var previouslyUsedNumbers: [Int] = []
    
    mutating func getRandomQuestion() -> Question {
        
        if (previouslyUsedNumbers.count == questions.count) {
            previouslyUsedNumbers = []
        }
        var randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: questions.count)
        
        // Picks a new random number if the previous one has been used
        while (previouslyUsedNumbers.contains(randomNumber)) {
            randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: questions.count)
        }
        previouslyUsedNumbers.append(randomNumber)
        
        return questions[randomNumber]
    }
}

class Question {
    
    let category: String
    let currentquestion: String
    let answers: [String]
    let correctAnswerIndex: Int
    
    init(category: String, currentquestion: String, answers: [String], correctAnswerIndex: Int) {
        self.category = category
        self.currentquestion = currentquestion
        self.answers = answers
        self.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex
    }
    
    func validateAnswer(to givenAnswer: String) -> Bool {
        return (givenAnswer == answers[correctAnswerIndex])
    }
    
    func getCurrentquestion() -> String {
        return currentquestion
    }
    
    func getAnswer() -> String {
        return answers[correctAnswerIndex]
    }
    
    func getChoices() -> [String] {
        return answers
    }
    
    func getAnswerAt(index: Int) -> String {
        return answers[index]
    }
}
```

And to display the question with answers on 4 buttons, I do it like this:

```
func displayQuestion() {
    
    currentQuestion = questions.getRandomQuestion()
    
    if let question = currentQuestion {
        let choices = question.getChoices()
        
        questionLabel.text = question.getCurrentquestion()
        answer1Button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)
        answer2Button.setTitle(choices[1], for: .normal)
        answer3Button.setTitle(choices[2], for: .normal)
        answer4Button.setTitle(choices[3], for: .normal)
        print(question.category)
        
    }

    // Display the current number of question out of all of them, ex: Question 1/3
    countLabel.text = "Question \(score.getQuestionsAsked()+1) / \(questions.questions.count)"
}
```

I am a bit stuck here. Have been search for a while but not found anything that would help, so I'll give this a try. Now what I want to do, is to categorize them, to only load the questions where category is equal to `Cat1` or `Cat2`, not both of them. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter function on sequences

```
let filteredCats = questions.filter { $0.category == "Cat1" || $0.category == "Cat2" }
let cat1s = questions.filter { $0.category == "Cat1" }
let cat2s = questions.filter { $0.category == "Cat1" }
let firstCat = questions.first { $0.category == "Cat1" } 

if let firstCat = firstCat {
    //Do your work here
}
```

## Reference

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/filter(_:)

Comment: Why do I get `Result of call to 'filter' is unused` with this code? I added the code above my `currentQuestion = questions.getRandomQuestion()`, is that correct?

Comment: assign it to a variable example: `let x = questions.filter { $0.category == "Cat1" || $0.category == "Cat2" }` use x in your code

Comment: My personal opinion it is better you learn the basics of Swift before building apps, it will help in the long run.Refer https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/

Comment: I will do that! I am pretty new to using dictionaries; But it still shows up all the questions, even if I changed it to `let x = questions.filter { $0.category == "Cat1"}`. How can I change my code to only display from `Cat1`?

Comment: This is what I have so far: https://pastebin.com/5x2BaQe8

Comment: I have updated my answer, but you really need to learn the basics, take the time to learn it. Asking for help is not a problem, but I think it is better to learn the fundamentals

Comment: Yea, I'm gonna do some more reading, looks like I need it! But I think I might be into something here: I've got this: https://pastebin.com/uUjs4bD3 , the question the shows up now is from Cat1, but since I am using `first`, only the first one shows up.

Comment: I found an easier solution for me. I create multiple dictionaries. One dictionary for each category, and I'll just sort them as `if (category == "Math") {`. I'll be a lot more code, but I'll work for now..

Comment: Glad you found the solution that suits your needs, even a dictionary can be like this [String: [Question]], this way String could be your Category and [Question] could be the questions in that category. Do what ever you feel comfortable with. Slowly spend a little time on the basics as well. Good luck!